# Retrieving a variable from a json object from twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I tried many way but I can't get access I keep getting undefined or can't access property of x in javascript.

Heres my object
http://pastebin.com/5kDBicRz

I tried a combination of JSON.prase and

```
 var posting = $.getJSON( url, { s: term } );
 data.statuses[1].id etc
```

but I'm having no luck. Can someone tell me how I can access id in statuses?

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault(); 
 var data;
 var $form = $(this),
 term = document.getElementById('search').value;
 url = $form.attr( "action" );
 var posting = $.getJSON( url, { s: term } );
  posting.done(function(data) {         
  console.log(data.statuses[1].id_str);      
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize you are misspeling statuses? data.statuses[1].id works fine

Comment: Typo but I'm still getting type error: cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: If you do var data= the json you posted, works fine, your error must be somewhere else

Comment: I'm doing echo json_encode($response); from the php to javascript. I checked all my code and I can't see what could be wrong.

Comment: rather log on the parsing side eg the client side script --> console.log("is your friend")

Answer (score 0):

hmn, why are you not using the variable u assigned it to ?

```
var posting = $.getJSON( url, { s: term } );
posting.statuses[1].id etc
```

why not use jquery ajax function with success handler ? and at least log the response ?

Comment: The method is async, `posting` will be `undefined` when you try and use it.

Comment: I was but it wasn't working so i thought that might of help. I tried that way but it still doesn't work.

Comment: there are i think called promises like posting.done(function(){ ...

from your question its just not clear whats in between the lines